# How to incorporate new look and feel in android?

Tags: user-interface, android

I'm coming from a web development background. I'n order to change the look and feel of the app  I simply apply a new css to get the look and feel.

How can I do this in android?

The only think I can see is stencils? But I don't quite understand stencils?

Can I  simply get hold of some file(s)/images and add it to the resources a suddenly my app looks stunning?

I'm really confused on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS equivalent in Android are [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). You can then apply a style of any of your components (i.e., have all your `TextView`s have a particular look). You may consider looking at the output of the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) (particularly the [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and the [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) tools) as examples of styles and themes.

Comment: Where can I purchase or get styles that are pre-packaged?

Comment: For the basic look and feel of your app, those two tools (Action Bar Style Generator and Holo Colors Generator) I linked to cover every built in UI component available and can be applied directly to your project for free. Beyond that you'll need to find designers and developers who can build something custom which is outside of the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

All layouts in android are made in xml files under the `res/layout`folders, but it's not as simple as changing a css files. All these xml files are connected to Java classes, where there may also be some layout changes.

You can edit colors and themes quite easily but you need some experience in native android development if you want to know what you're doing.

Comment: The issue is I"m not a designer. How can I buy a package that is pre-packaged with images etc what ever is required?